# No Persistence provider for EntityManager named

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, toplink

I have my `persistence.xml` with the same name using `TopLink` under the `META-INF` directory.
Then, I have my code calling it with:

```
EntityManagerFactory emfdb = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("agisdb");
```

Yet, I got the following error message:

```
2009-07-21 09:22:41,018 [main] ERROR - No Persistence provider for EntityManager named agisdb
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named agisdb
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:89)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:60)
```

Here is the `persistence.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="agisdb">
        <class>com.agis.livedb.domain.AddressEntity</class>
        <class>com.agis.livedb.domain.TrafficCameraEntity</class>
        <class>com.agis.livedb.domain.TrafficPhotoEntity</class>
        <class>com.agis.livedb.domain.TrafficReportEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="toplink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/agisdb"/>
            <property name="toplink.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="toplink.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="toplink.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

It should have been in the classpath. Yet, I got the above error.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

After `<persistence-unit name="agisdb">`, define the persistence provider name:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

Comment: I am using Derby and it wasn't necessary to specify this (I did, but then removed it once I solved the problem, just to make sure). I was getting the error finally because persistence.xml was not in the src/META-INF folder, even though it had been in a folder in the Eclipse source path for the project. I'm thinking somewhere it's hard-wired to be on src/*

Comment: **this was not necessary in my case, but *classpathing* hibernate-entitymanager*.jar** as stated in *Ualter Jr*s answer below. I am using a standalone GWT app with *hibernate-core-4.3.7.jar*, *hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar* and *hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.jar*.

Comment: Same with @AndreasDietrich, after replacing "hibernate-core-4.3.10" artifact with "hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10" in pom.xml (I use maven), this error is gone. Actually, http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/ says that you should use "hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.10" for JPA.

Comment: Apart from this, I also had to **move up from hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA to 3.6.10.Final**. Just in case you still have a legacy codebase using Hibernate 3.

Comment: I'm a bit suprised you don't run into a problem with your `<provider/>`, while using hibernate-4 you should change your provider to `<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23041964/jpa-2-1-hibernate-4-3-deprecation-warning .

Comment: It's also possible that your maven project isn't generating the classpath in `Manifest.mf`. Check the contents of this file in your generated war.

Answer (score 91):

Put the `"hibernate-entitymanager.jar"` in the classpath of application.
For newer versions, you should use `"hibernate-core.jar"` instead of the deprecated `hibernate-entitymanager`

If you are running through some IDE, like **Eclipse**: `Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries.`

Otherwise put it in the `/lib` of your application.

Comment: Took me a few hours to figure this was the cause. For other people searching for this bloody jar, in case of Hibernate 4.1.3, its in hibernate-release-4.1.3.Final\lib\jpa\hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.3.Final.jar

Comment: And for those of us who are using Maven, that would be groupid `org.hibernate` artifactid `hibernate-entitymanager`

Comment: It's been eclipselink.jar for me, which was missing in the path. No hibernate*something.jar in the path at all.

Comment: Just spent a few hours confirming persistence.xml was on class path, and comparing every facet of a project this worked for and a project it didn't work for. Very misleading error message since it can happen if persistence.xml is missing, if the PU with that name is missing, or apparently if a hibernate jar is missing!

Comment: For me it was `org.eclipse.persistence.jpa` with scope test.

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
   </dependency>

Comment: "For newer versions, you should use `hibernate-core.jar` instead of the deprecated `hibernate-entitymanager`" - THANK YOU.  I tried a bunch before this worked for me.  Is this documented somewhere besides stackoverflow?

Answer (score 70):

Make sure that the `persistence.xml` file is in the directory: `<webroot>/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF`

Comment: this didn't work for me, brought the Persistence unit not found: 'null' error. Moving it back to /src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml

Comment: I guess this applies for those who's using **toplink** (or other web-related stuff), for everyone else other answers here may be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, for me the path is target/classes/META-INF

Comment: Same, for some weird reason it needs to be in a META-INF directory, otherwise won't work...

Answer (score 22):

Faced the same issue and couldn't find solution for quite a long time. In my case it helped to replace

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

with

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

Took solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22103666/838444)

Comment: Was upgrading from Hibernate 4.3.5 to 5.2.12 and this provider name change fixed the problem for me. That setting appears to allow JPA to use the core .jar file instead of the entity-manger .jar that shows as deprecated on the Maven central repository. Thanks so much for sharing.

Answer (score 19):

I needed this in my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Works for version 4.3.11.

Comment: It's deprecated, see above. Use hibernate-core instead.

Answer (score 10):

There is another point: If you face this problem within an Eclipse RCP environment, you might have to change the Factory generation from `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory` to `new PersistenceProvider().createEntityManagerFactory`

see [ECF](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=541155&) for a detailed discussion on this.

Comment: This was the exact problem I was having with org.eclipse.persistence.jpa 2.4.0. I literally spent 2 hours pulling my hair out wondering why it couldn't find my persisence.xml. All the examples do not seem to incorporate this. oh well ... many many thanks!

Comment: 'PersistenceProvider' is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you defined one provider like `<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>` but referencing another one in jar. That happened with me: my persistence.xml provider was openjpa but I was using eclipselink in my classpath.
Hope this help!

Answer (score 6):

Quick advice:

- check if persistence.xml is in your classpath
- check if hibernate provider is in your classpath

With using JPA in standalone application (outside of JavaEE), a persistence provider needs to be specified somewhere. This can be done in two ways that I know of:

- either add provider element into the persistence unit: `<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>` (as described in correct answere by Chris: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1285436/784594)
- or provider for interface javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider must be specified as a service, see here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html (this is usually included when you include hibernate,or another JPA implementation, into your classpath

In my case, I found out that due to maven misconfiguration, hibernate-entitymanager jar was not included as a dependency, even if it was a transient dependency of other module.

Comment: /facepalm - I forgot to add the maven dependency for the hibernate provider.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Eclipse make sure that exclusion pattern does not remove your `persistence.xml` from source folders on build path.

1. Go to **Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source** tab
2. Check your exclusion pattern which is located at
   `MyProject/src/main/java -> Excluded: <your_pattern>`
   tree node
3. Optionally, set it to `Excluded: (None)` by selecting the node and clicking **Edit...** button on the left.

Comment: Solved my problem. Excluded pattern was set to "**" after a fetch/pull. I don't know why...

Answer (score 5):

I'm some years late to the party here but I hit the same exception while trying to get Hibernate 3.5.1 working with HSQLDB and a desktop JavaFX program. I got it to work with the help of this thread and a lot of trial and error. It seems you get this error for a whole variety of problems:

```
No Persistence provider for EntityManager named mick
```

I tried building the hibernate tutorial examples but because I was using Java 10 I wasn't able to get them to build and run easily. I gave up on that, not really wanting to waste time fixing its problems. Setting up a module-info.java file (Jigsaw) is another hairball many people haven't discovered yet.

Somewhat confusing is that these (below) were the only two files I needed in my build.gradle file. The Hibernate documentation isn't clear about exactly which Jars you need to include. Entity-manager was causing confusion and is no longer required in the latest Hibernate version, and neither is javax.persistence-api. Note, I'm using Java 10 here so I had to include the jaxb-api, to get around some xml-bind errors, as well as add an entry for the java persistence module in my module-info.java file.

Build.gradle

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core
compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.3.1.Final')

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api
compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.0'
```

Module-info.java

```
// Used for HsqlDB - add the hibernate-core jar to build.gradle too
requires java.persistence;
```

With hibernate 5.3.1 you don't need to specify the provider, below, in your persistence.xml file. If one is not provided the Hibernate provider is chosen by default.

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

The persistence.xml file should be located in the correct directory so:

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml
```

Stepping through the hibernate source code in the Intellij debugger, where it checks for a dialect, also threw the exact same exception, because of a missing dialect property in the persistence.xml file. I added this (add the correct one for your DB type):

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
```

I still got the same exception after this, so stepping through the debugger again in Intellij revealed the test entity I was trying to persist (simple parent-child example) had missing annotations for the OneToMany, ManyToOne relationships. I fixed this and the exception went away and my entities were persisted ok.

Here's my full final persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
         version="2.1">

<persistence-unit name="mick" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <description>
        Persistence unit for the JPA tutorial of the Hibernate Getting Started Guide
    </description>

    <!-- Provided in latest release of hibernate
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    -->

    <class>com.micks.scenebuilderdemo.database.Parent</class>
    <class>com.micks.scenebuilderdemo.database.Child</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver"/>

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                  value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:./database/database;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=TRUE"/>

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

I probably wasted about half a day on this gem. My advice would be to start very simple - a single test entity with one or two fields, as it seems like this exception can have many causes.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the configuration details Really helped resolving it.

Answer (score 4):

Corner case: if you are using m2Eclipse, it automatically puts in excludes on your resources folders. Then when you try to run tests inside eclipse, the subsequent absence of persistence.xml will produce this error.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have created persistence.xml file under the 'src' folder. I created under the project folder and that was my problem.

Comment: Eclipse 4.4.0 doesn't want to nest SRC folders, so I was putting META-INF at the top level, thinking persistence.xml being on the classpath would be adequate. NOT! I had to create manually a src/META-INF (in the operating system) and move the persistence.xml file by hand. Perhaps it's possible to do this in Eclipse, but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Maven, it could be that it is not looking at the right place for the META-INF folder. Others have mentioned copying the folder, but another way that worked for me was to tell Maven where to look for it, using the `<resources>` tag. See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html

Answer (score 2):

It happenes when the entity manager is trying to point to many persistence units. Do the following steps:

1. open the related file in your editor (provided your project has been closed in your IDE)
2. delete all the persistence and entity manager related code
3. save the file
4. open the project in your IDE
5. now bind the db or table of your choice

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, but on [EclipseLink version 2.5.0](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/).

I solved my problem by adding yet another jar file which was necessarily (**javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar.jar**);

Jars needed:
     - javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar
     - eclipselink.jar
     - jdbc.jar (depending on the database used).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this error but the issue was the namespace uri in the `persistence.xml`.

I replaced `http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence` to `http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence` and the version 2.1 to 2.0.

It's now working.

Comment: That's exactly what happened for me using Tomcat.. I just added a full header to clarify for new users

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the hibernate-entitymanager-x.jar in the classpath.

In Hibernate 4.x, if the jar is present, then no need to add the org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence in persistence.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, previously I use idea to generate entity by database schema, and the `persistence.xml` is automatically generated in `src/main/java/META-INF`,and according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/23890419/10701129, I move it to `src/main/resources/META-INF`, also marked META-INF as source root. It works for me.

But just simply marking original META-INF(that is, src/main/java/META-INF) as source root, doesn't work, which confuses me.

and this is the structre:
[image]

Comment: This was my solution too. I have a maven project and i created manually this folder (META-INF) under resources. Then i made sure that in war file META-INF folder was placed under: \WEB-INF\classes\META-INF

Answer (score 1):

The question has been answered already, but just wanted to post a tip that was holding me up. This exception was being thrown after previous errors. I was getting this:

```
property toplink.platform.class.name is deprecated, property toplink.target-database should be used instead.
```

Even though I had changed the persistence.xml to include the new property name:

```
<property name="toplink.target-database" value="oracle.toplink.platform.database.oracle.Oracle10Platform"/>
```

Following the message about the deprecated property name I was getting the same PersistenceException like above and a whole other string of exceptions. My tip: make sure to check the beginning of the exception sausage.

There seems to be a bug in Glassfish v2.1.1 where redeploys or undeploys and deploys are not updating the persistence.xml, which is being cached somewhere. I had to restart the server and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In an OSGi-context, it's necessary to list your persistence units in the bundle's MANIFEST.MF, e.g.

```
JPA-PersistenceUnits: my-persistence-unit
```

Otherwise, the JPA-bundle won't know your bundle contains persistence units.

See http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/OSGi/Developing_with_EclipseLink_OSGi_in_PDE .

Answer (score 1):

You need the following jar files in the classpath:

1. antlr-2.7.6.jar
2. commons-collections-3.1.jar
3. dom4j-1.6.1.jar
4. hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
5. hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar
6. hibernate-entitymanager.jar
7. hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
8. javassist-3.9.0.jar
9. jboss-logging-3.1.1.GA.jar
10. jta-1.1.jar
11. slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
12. xxx-jdbc-driver.jar

Answer (score 1):

I just copied the META-INF into src and worked!

Answer (score 1):

**Hibernate 5.2.5**
Jar Files Required in the class path. This is within a required folder of Hibernate 5.2.5 Final release. It can be downloaded from http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/

1. antlr-2.7.7
2. cdi-api-1.1
3. classmate-1.3.0
4. dom4j-1.6.1
5. el-api-2.2
6. geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1
7. hibernate-commons-annotation-5.0.1.Final
8. hibernate-core-5.2.5.Final
9. hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final
10. jandex-2.0.3.Final
11. javassist-3.20.0-GA
12. javax.inject-1
13. jboss-interceptor-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Beta1
14. jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final
15. jsr250-api-1.0

Create an xml file **"persistence.xml"** in

**YourProject/src/META-INF/persistence.xml**

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
         version="2.1">

<persistence-unit name="sample">

    <class>org.pramod.data.object.UserDetail</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate_project"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>

        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>

        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

1. please note down the information mentioned in the < persistance > tag and version should be 2.1.
2. please note the name < persistance-unit > tag, name is mentioned as **"sample"**. This name needs to be used exactly same while loading your

**EntityManagerFactor = Persistance.createEntityManagerFactory("sample");**. "sample" can be changed as per your naming convention.

Now create a Entity class. with name as per my example UserDetail, in the package **org.pramod.data.object**

UserDetail.java

```
package org.pramod.data.object;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_detail")
public class UserDetail {
    @Id
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="user_name")
    private String userName;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }   
    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return "UserDetail [id=" + id + ", userName=" + userName + "]";
    }
}
```

Now create a class with main method.

HibernateTest.java

```
package org.pramod.hibernate;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import org.pramod.data.object.UserDetail;

public class HibernateTest {
    private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        UserDetail user = new UserDetail();
        user.setId(1);
        user.setUserName("Pramod Sharma");

        try {
            entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("sample");
            EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            entityManager.persist( user );
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            System.out.println("successfull");
            entityManager.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Output will be

```
UserDetail [id=1, userName=Pramod Sharma]
Hibernate: drop table if exists user_details
Hibernate: create table user_details (user_id integer not null, user_name varchar(255), primary key (user_id))
Hibernate: insert into user_details (user_name, user_id) values (?, ?)
successfull
```

Answer (score 1):

I had already set up persistence.xml and installed all the Hibernate dependencies and was still stuck with this error.

In my case, I had imported the wrong `Persistence` class.

I replaced
`import javax.persistence.Persistence`
with
`import jakarta.persistence.Persistence`

This solved it. I wish the error message was more descriptive or helpful but there you have it.

Answer (score 0):

If there are different names in `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPAService")` in different classes than you get the error. **By refactoring it is possible to get different names** which was in my case. In one class the auto-generated `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPAService")`in `private void initComponents()`, ContactsTable class differed from `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPAServiceExtended")` in DBManager class.

Answer (score 0):

Mine got resolved by adding   info in persistence.xml  e.g. `<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>` and then making sure you have the library on classpath e.g. in Maven add dependency like

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify the peristent unit name

```
<persistence-unit name="com.myapp.model.jpa"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">    
public static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "com.myapp.model.jpa";
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(**PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME**);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was about mistake in two properties as below. When I changed them ‘No Persistence provider for EntityManager named’ disappered.

So you could try test connection with your properties to check if everything is correct.

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="...”/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="...”/>
```

Strange error, I was totally confused because of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try also copying the persistence.xml manually to the folder `<project root>\bin\META-INF`. This fixed the problem in Eclipse Neon with `EclipseLink 2.5.2` using a simple plug-in project.

Answer (score 0):

**Had the same issue,  but this actually worked for me :**

```
mvn install -e  -Dmaven.repo.local=$WORKSPACE/.repository.
```

NB : The maven command above will reinstall all your project dependencies from scratch. Your console will be loaded with verbose logs due to the network request maven is making.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the absolute path of the file otherwise this will not work. Then with that path we build the file and pass it to the configuration.

```
@Throws(HibernateException::class)
fun getSessionFactory() : SessionFactory {
    return Configuration()
                .configure(getFile())
                .buildSessionFactory()
    }


private fun getFile(canonicalName: String): File {
    val absolutePathCurrentModule = System.getProperty("user.dir")
    val pathFromProjectRoot = absolutePathCurrentModule.dropLastWhile { it != '/' }
    val absolutePathFromProjectRoot = "${pathFromProjectRoot}module-name/src/main/resources/$canonicalName"
    println("Absolute Path of secret-hibernate.cfg.xml: $absolutePathFromProjectRoot")
    return File(absolutePathFromProjectRoot)
}
```

GL

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4033090/5279996)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I removed "@ManagedBean" from my bean class now working.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when I moved all my java classes to a different package.
Finally, I figured out that if I change the packages of myclasses, then I need to update persistence.xml with the new packages in all the persistence-unit/class elements that refer to my java classes.