# How to get the real path of Java application at runtime?

Tags: java, filepath

I am creating a Java application where I am using log4j. I have given the absolute path of configuration log4j file and also an absolute path of generated log file(where this log file are generated). I can get the absolute path of a Java web application at run time via:

```
String prefix =  getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
```

but in the context of a normal Java application, what can we use?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Try;

```
String path = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();
```

Comment: There's also `System.getProperty("user.dir")`, which can't throw an `IOException`.

Comment: Does this really return the directory where the application is installed?  It looks like it should return the working directory, which is not necessarily the same thing.

Comment: Tested this and it returns the working directory, not the application's directory.

Answer (score 37):

It isn't clear what you're asking for. I don't know what 'with respect to the web application we are using' means if `getServletContext().getRealPath()` isn't the answer, but:

- The current user's current working directory is given by `System.getProperty("user.dir")`
- The current user's home directory is given by `System.getProperty("user.home")`
- The location of the JAR file from which the current class was loaded is given by `this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()`.

Comment: @Gary Did you look at the documentation before posting that? It is the current working directory. `user.home` is the user's home directory.

Comment: @Jonathan Sorry. You're quite right and I'm wrong. Too much coffee today!

Comment: I am upvoting this. 
I didn't get solution of my problem from this post, but this code was what i need for my project. 
(getting path of running java application and add the path to java.path -my dll is always in this path-)

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

And what about using `this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()`?

Answer (score 7):

Since the application path of a `JAR` and an application running from inside an `IDE` differs, I wrote the following code to consistently return the correct current directory:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class ProgramDirectoryUtilities
{
    private static String getJarName()
    {
        return new File(ProgramDirectoryUtilities.class.getProtectionDomain()
                .getCodeSource()
                .getLocation()
                .getPath())
                .getName();
    }

    private static boolean runningFromJAR()
    {
        String jarName = getJarName();
        return jarName.contains(".jar");
    }

    public static String getProgramDirectory()
    {
        if (runningFromJAR())
        {
            return getCurrentJARDirectory();
        } else
        {
            return getCurrentProjectDirectory();
        }
    }

    private static String getCurrentProjectDirectory()
    {
        return new File("").getAbsolutePath();
    }

    private static String getCurrentJARDirectory()
    {
        try
        {
            return new File(ProgramDirectoryUtilities.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()).getParent();
        } catch (URISyntaxException exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Simply call `getProgramDirectory()` and you should be good either way.

Comment: I know it's old, but I'm still getting different results between running the app and running the unit test, both from within IDE. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about a web application, you should use the `getRealPath` from a `ServletContext` object.

Example:

```
public class MyServlet extends Servlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
              throws ServletException, IOException{
         String webAppPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but here i am using simple Java application.

Comment: @SameekMishra So why did you mention a Web application?

Answer (score 2):

I use this method to get complete path to jar or exe.

```
File pto = new File(YourClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());

pto.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new File(".").getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: Return the working directory and not the application directory.
So, when press enter on a file to open with the application, we take wrong application path.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to save files into a sub-directory of user.home than wherever the app. might reside.

Sun went to considerable effort to ensure that applets and apps. launched using Java Web Start cannot determine the apps. real path.  This change broke many apps. I would not be surprised if the changes are extended to other apps.

Answer (score 1):

```
/*****************************************************************************
     * return application path
     * @return
     *****************************************************************************/
    public static String getApplcatonPath(){
        CodeSource codeSource = MainApp.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
        File rootPath = null;
        try {
            rootPath = new File(codeSource.getLocation().toURI().getPath());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
        return rootPath.getParentFile().getPath();
    }//end of getApplcatonPath()
```

Comment: This code will throw a `NullPointerException` if there is somehow a `URISyntaxException`.

Comment: this will not throw NullPointerException

Comment: Of cours it will throw an NPE. `rootPath` is null and never changes in the exception case, and then you dereference it. If you want to debate, provide facts or arguments. Not just denial.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the real path of java web application such as Spring (Servlet), you can get it from Servlet Context object that comes with your HttpServletRequest.

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String index(ModelMap m, HttpServletRequest request) {
    String realPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    System.out.println(realPath);
    return "index";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think everyone's missing a key problem with this.

```
String prefix =  getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
```

The servlet instance could be on one of the arbitrarily many nodes and doesn't technically require a file system at all.

In Java EE containers for example the application could be loaded from a database or even a directory server.  Different parts of the application can also be running on different nodes.  Access to the world outside the application is provided by the application server.

Use java.util.logging or Apache Commons Logging if you have to maintain compatibility with legacy log4j.  Tell the application server where the log file is supposed to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` and `System.getProperty("path.separator")` are better schemes.
eg:

```java
private final static String JAR_SUFFIX = ".jar";

public static String getJarRuntimePath(){
        String javaClassPath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
        String pathSeparator = System.getProperty("path.separator");
        if(javaClassPath.contains(pathSeparator)){
            javaClassPath = filePath.substring(0,filePath.indexOf(pathSeparator));
        }else if (javaClassPath.endsWith(JAR_SUFFIX)) {
            javaClassPath = filePath.substring(0, filePath.lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1);
        }
        File serverLocalConfig = new File(javaClassPath);
        return serverLocalConfig.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4033033/10560907

You must add import statement like this:

`import java.io.File;`

in very beginning java source code.

like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43553093/10560907

Comment: If you want to use the first answer you would be wrong. The second answer you give is correct.

Answer (score -1):

I have a file "cost.ini" on the root of my class path. My JAR file is named "cost.jar".

The following code:

- If we have a JAR file, takes the directory where the JAR file is.

  If we have *.class files, takes the directory of the root of classes.

```
try {
    //JDK11: replace "UTF-8" with UTF_8 and remove try-catch
    String rootPath = decode(getSystemResource("cost.ini").getPath()
            .replaceAll("(cost\\.jar!/)?cost\\.ini$|^(file\\:)?/", ""), "UTF-8");
    showMessageDialog(null, rootPath, "rootpath", WARNING_MESSAGE);
} catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {}
```

Path returned from `.getPath()` has the format:

In JAR: `file:/C:/folder1/folder2/cost.jar!/cost.ini`

In *.class: `/C:/folder1/folder2/cost.ini`

Every use of `File`, leads on exception, if the application provided in JAR format.

Comment: I don't understand the down voting. Method works both for jar and not jar application. Because on release you use jar but on debug you use a banch of java classes.

Answer (score -2):

The expression

```
new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
```

will get you the current working directory associated with the execution of JVM. However, the JVM does provide a wealth of other useful properties via the

```
System.getProperty(propertyName);
```

interface. A list of these properties [can be found here](http://www.mindspring.com/~mgrand/java-system-properties.htm).

These will allow you to reference the current users directory, the temp directory and so on in a platform independent manner.

Comment: But not one of those system properties, or any other, provides an answer to the question.