# FileNotFoundException when using the reference path

Tags: java, file, exception, filenotfoundexception

My project has two folders: `folder1` and `folder2`.
In `folder1`, I am trying to load a file present in folder2 using its reference path but it gives me the following exception: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /folder2/blah.txt (No such file or directory)`. It works when I use the absolute path.

```
file = new FileInputStream("/folder2/blah.txt")
```

Comment: Do folder1 and folder2 have the same parent?

Comment: @helpYou yes they do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always call the paths by calling the root path of the application. I am assuming folder1 and folder2 are not related, meaning, folder2 is not in folder1 and thats why it is happening.

Please check [How to get the real path of Java application at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032957/how-to-get-the-real-path-of-java-application-at-runtime) to get the root path then you can access the directories as you please

In other means you can try:

```
String path = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();
file = new FileInputStream( path + "/folder2/blah.txt"); // I have not tested here. If it returns an error try removing the / from the beginning of the folder2
```

Answer (score -1):

It is a pretty simple fix. You are trying to load the file in your system at /folder2/blah.properties. However, if it is just in your Java project's classpath the initial File path separator is omitted.

Try something like this:

```
//Initial seperator is oitted.
file = new FileInputStream("folder2/blah.txt")
```

Comment: Same exception is returned