# get App working directory - JAVA

Tags: java, c#, working-directory

I'm Making my first step going from C# to JAVA and have plenty of stuff that I dont get .. :(
I was searching for a way to get current directory in JAVA

and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032957/how-to-get-the-real-path-of-java-application-at-runtime) answer(one of many one ) :

```
String path = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();
```

my question is  : what is the role of `File(".")` + what is going under the hood ?

I got used to `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();` and never asked my self how is it working

Comment: It looks like an attempt to get a path to the user's directory. Something I usually do `System.getProperty("user.dir")` for.

Comment: `"."` is simply the path to the current directory, that's all.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels can you please explain ? , this is "." like you see in Linux ?