# How to save URI of serialized Object between sessions?

Tags: java, serialization, jar

I want to save which recipe collection was last loaded into the application. The path of the most recently loaded serialized recipe collection object is stored in a .ser file inside the jar file of the application. And of course I can read this .ser file no Problem by using this `getRessourceAsStream()` method. But writing doesn't seem to be possible. So how do I best save this .ser file storing the URI to the last loaded serialized object, so that writing is also possible?

EDIT: I don't want to save INSIDE a .jar because `Class.getResourceAsStream(String)` as used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056682/how-can-my-java-program-store-files-inside-of-its-jar-file) only returns an INPUTStream, but I need an OUTputStream to write to a file, which doesn't seem to be possible for .jar resources. So I want to know how I can accomplish what I need, saving an object in a .ser file which can be written to and read by the .jar, with the file stored outside of the .jar.

Comment: Are you looking to [store files inside a jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056682/how-can-my-java-program-store-files-inside-of-its-jar-file)?

Comment: I look for a way to "save URI of serialized Object between sessions", I currently have a .ser file inside the .jar of my program that saves the URI of a serialized object which is the most recent selected via a Filechooser in the application. My goal is when the user opens the application again that the last selected recipe collection is loaded. But you can't write to a Ressource(which is needed when another collection is loaded) because getRessourceAsStream() is actually an inputstream, so where and how should I save this .ser file containing the URI of the last loaded recipe collection?

Comment: Don't just completely repeat yourself. Answer the question, and take the hint. This is a duplicate. Then read the duplicate. You can't do this.

Comment: @EJP I don't get it, I repeated myself to explain how I actually DON'T want to save inside a .jar, because I already tried and in some thread I read that you shouldn't store resources that are written to inside a .jar, because that could cause problems and as I explained many times before if you access resources by using Class.getResourceAsStream(String) it only returns an inputstream, am I stating things so unclear?

Comment: I am unable to make any sense out of  'a .ser file which can be written to and read from the .JAR' if it doesn't mean exactly what you are now disclaiming.

Comment: 'a .ser file which can be written to and read from the .JAR' don't you know what a .ser file is, or what? I don't get what you are not getting :D. I want to know how/where to save this file and how to best access it, so how to get the path and so on. For example you have a directory and there you have the .jar and the .ser, how could you then access that file(the .ser from the .jar), if everything is set up as I described? I hope it got a bit clearer now :).

Comment: You are trying to write a .ser file into the .jar file, according to the words I quoted, which makes your question a duplicate. If that isn't what you mean, you have completely failed to make yourself clear.

Comment: "I don't want to save INSIDE a .jar because Class.getResourceAsStream(String) as used here only returns an INPUTStream, but I need an OUTputStream to write to a file, which doesn't seem to be possible for .jar resources. So I want to know how I can accomplish what I need, saving an object in a .ser file which can be written to and read [by] the .jar, with the .ser stored outside of the .jar." I may have used the wrong preposition, sorry, in the German language you use them differently...

Comment: So is your question really how to know the location of the .jar file?

Comment: In which case see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032957/how-to-get-the-real-path-of-java-application-at-runtime/4033090#4033090).

Comment: Yeah thanks, already figured it out, I guess I was a bit confused because I dealt with this I/O crap for a few days now and kinda lost it so to say :D. I guess I can continue now...