# No Persistence provider for EntityManager when trying to execute query in JPAQL console (IntelliJ Idea 11)

Tags: maven, console, intellij-idea, jpa-2.0

I want to set up JPAQL console in IntelliJ Idea 11. I have my persistence unit defined and when i open JPAQL console and i run the query i get the following error:

```
jpa-ql> select l from FourPmLog l
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named primary
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:69)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
in JpaFacadeImpl.createEntityManagerFactory(JpaFacadeImpl.java:16)
in RemoteUtil.executeWithClassLoader(RemoteUtil.java:132)
in RemoteUtil$3$1.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:91)
in JpaEngine.ensureInitialized(JpaEngine.java:129)
```

The project is imported from Maven (JavaEE6/Jboss7 archetype; EAR package) and when i run this app on JBoss7 everything works ok.

How do i make it work?

Comment: Check that persistence-unit/provider tag is not missing. Post your `persistence.xml` if it's not the case.

Comment: I want to use hibernate but i don't know the right value for a provider tag. I use "<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>" configuration but it doesn't seem to work. I have hibernate-jpa-2.0-api and hibernate-core in my pom.xml (provided scope).

Comment: Did you already check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1158159/104891?

Comment: I did check the link above and i set provider as "<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>" in persistence.xml but Idea doesn't seem to find it even though i include hibernate-core (version 4.*) jar in my pom.xml. I also included the hibernate-entitymanager jar but it doesn't seem to make any difference either.

Comment: Check that `org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.1.2.Final` is added to the pom dependencies.