# JPA and Spring MVC wrong configuration?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-mvc

I get this exception when I try to run my test web application:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'myDAO': 
Injection of persistence dependencies failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'emf' defined in ServletContext resource 
[/WEB-INF/testapp-servlet.xml]:
Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: 
No Persistence provider for EntityManager named testapp
```

My `persistence.xml` file is in `META-INF` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
<persistence-unit name="testapp" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>it.testapp.entities.Person</class>
    <class>it.testapp.entities.Group</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=db_testapp" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user1" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

My `data-context.xml` bean definiton file is into `WEB-INF` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">


<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="it.testapp.dao" />

<bean id="emf"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="testapp"></property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="aDao" class="it.testapp.dao.jpa.PersonJpaDAO" />
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158159/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named

Comment: @CarlosGavidia same problem, but I cannot resolve...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to add a `<provider>` tag under `<persistence-unit>`?

(e.g. `<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>`)

Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1856503/836738) suggested that not having your `persistence.xml` in `/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF` might also trigger this error.

Comment: It's not a different exception or anything?  If not, is `org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence` in your classpath?

Comment: Same exception... I'm using Hibernate 4, so have `hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.1.Final.jar` in my classpath

Comment: Sorry, the problem was that my `persistence.xml` was in `/WebContent/META_INF` (I'm using Eclipse) and not into `/src/META-INF`. Thank you very much!