# How to get usernames by their id with Hibernate and JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entries")
public class Entry {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long user_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;


    public Long getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(Long user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Transient
    private String confirmPassword;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "users", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Entry> attachments = new HashSet<Entry>();


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getConfirmPassword() {
        return confirmPassword;
    }

    public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
        this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }   

}
```

[image: My database]

This rows in my entities cause error on startup of my application:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private User user;**

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "users", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Entry> attachments = new HashSet<Entry>();
```

My error on startup:

> 05-Apr-2017 19:34:11.786 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring
>   WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath 05-Apr-2017
>   19:34:11.933 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring
>   root WebApplicationContext 05-Apr-2017 19:34:14.088 SEVERE [RMI TCP
>   Connection(4)-127.0.0.1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception
>   sending context initialized event to listener instance of class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/appconfig-data.xml]: Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default]
>   Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1045)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:824)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4754)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5216)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1702)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
>     at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default]
>   Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory  at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:120)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:860)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
>     ... 57 more Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy
>   reference an unknown target entity property:
>   net.proselyte.springsecurityapp.model.Entry.users in
>   net.proselyte.springsecurityapp.model.User.attachments    at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:769)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:729)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:70)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1697)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1426)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
>     ... 65 more
>
> 05-Apr-2017 19:34:14.106 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root
>   WebApplicationContext

I want to get all my entries with joined table - users. I am trying to get entries like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/entries", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String entries(Model model) {
        List<Entry> entries = entryService.findAllEntries();
        model.addAttribute("entries", entries); 
        return "entry";
    }
```

My appconfig-data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="net.proselyte.springsecurityapp.model"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>



    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="net.proselyte.springsecurityapp.dao"/>
</beans>
```

What is my error with relations that doesn't allow me start the application and how implement query with joining?

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: @MouseEvent sorry, updated

Comment: Can you provide us your pom and all configuration xml including persistence.xml, cause this might be configuration issue.

Comment: It would be nice if you post the complete stack trace

Comment: @prasanth thank you, updated

Comment: where did you place persistence.xml file?

Comment: @ShaikElias I don't have persistence.xml but I have appconfig-data.xml, I have added its content to my answers body, thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454945/caused-by-org-hibernate-annotationexception-mappedby-reference-an-unknown-targ

Comment: `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: net.proselyte.springsecurityapp.model.Entry.users in net.proselyte.springsecurityapp.model.User.attachments`

Comment: Also, remove the user_id field, which is useless, and will also cause an exception to bt thrown, since user is already mapped to the same column.

Comment: Your using jpa, so you need to have persistence.xml file in /WEB-INF/classes/META-INF http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110462/jpa-and-spring-mvc-wrong-configuration

Comment: @JBNizet and others thank you very much, it finally works!