# "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named manager1" error with JPA 2.0 and Spring 3.1

Tags: java, spring, jpa, persistence

I'm working now on a project using Spring 3.1 and JPA 2.0 and i'm getting an log message error telling me : "**No Persistence provider for EntityManager named manager1**".

Here's my persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="DemoSpringCore" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>app.demo.model.Operation</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3309/test"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Here's my managed enity "Operation.java" :
    package app.demo.model;

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="operation")
public class Operation implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Column(name="a",length=9)
private int a;

@Column(name="b",length=9)
private int b;

@Column(name="c",length=10)
private int c;

public int getA() {
    return a;
}
public void setA(int a) {
    this.a = a;
}
public int getB() {
    return b;
}
public void setB(int b) {
    this.b = b;
}
public int getC() {
    return c;
}
public void setC(int c) {
    this.c = c;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

Here's my java configuration file "AppConfiguration.java" the alternative of "ApplicationContext.xml" in Spring 3.1 :

```
package app.demo.config;

import java.util.Properties;
import com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import app.demo.dao.OperationDAO;
import app.demo.dao.OperationDAOImpl;
import app.demo.service.OperationServiceImpl;
import app.demo.service.OperationService;
import org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("/META-INF/application.properties")
public class AppConfiguration {

private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL = "hibernate.format_sql";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
// private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY =
// "hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy";

@Resource
private Environment environment;

@Bean(name = "operationServiceBean")
public OperationService operationService() {
    return new OperationServiceImpl();
}

@Bean(name = "operationDAOBean")
public OperationDAO operationDAO() {
    return new OperationDAOImpl();
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {

    BoneCPDataSource dataSource = new BoneCPDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClass(environment
            .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(environment
            .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment
            .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment
            .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

    return (DataSource) dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean()
        throws ClassNotFoundException {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    entityManagerFactoryBean
            .setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);

    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());

    Properties jpaProterties = new Properties();
    jpaProterties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, environment
            .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
    jpaProterties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL, environment
            .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL));
    jpaProterties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, environment
            .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
    jpaProterties
            .put(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN,
                    environment
                            .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
    // jpaProterties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY,
    // environment
    // .getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY));
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProterties);

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}
}
```

and finally my "application.properties" where i put datasource connection properties :

```
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3309/test
db.username=root
db.password=root

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.show_sql=true

entitymanager.packages.to.scan=app.demo.model
```

P.S : I used both methods "appliaction.properties" and also "persistence.xml" each one alone and after both of them in the same time in hope that'll work but nothing happenned !
Moreover i added the provider attribute in both "AppConfiguration.java" and "persistence.xml" and i verified the existence of all dependencies jar files !

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [No Persistence provider for EntityManager named ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158159/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named)

Answer (score 0):

You must set the packages to scan directly in the emf, and also set the persistence unit name:

```
entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(...);
entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName(...);
```

after this you don't even need the persistence.xml anymore.

Also I would recommend (if you get rid of the persistence.xml anyway) to use the correct jpa properties for the basic ones:

```
javax.persistence.jdbc.driver
javax.persistence.jdbc.url
javax.persistence.jdbc.user
javax.persistence.jdbc.password
```