# gwt +Spring 3+Jpa org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: spring, gwt, spring-4-gwt

I am trying to integrate Spring 3,Jpa and Gwt using Spring4gwt , but I am getting an exception while spring tries to create a Bean , my xml and the error stack trace below:

Note :I am not using maven

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="man.artis" />

<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" scheduler="myScheduler"/>

<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5"/>

<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10"/>

<tx:annotation-driven/>


<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="amine" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

web.xml

```
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.spring4gwt.server.SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet
</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rututto/springGwtServices/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="amine" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" >
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>man.artis.shared.dto.CustomerDTO</class>

     <properties>

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=SPRING" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="artisanat" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="artisanat" />

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
         <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300"/>
         <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
         <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000"/>

        </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

DAO:

```
@Repository("customerDAO")
```

public class CustomerDAO extends JpaDAO {

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "amine")
EntityManagerFactory EntityManagerFactory;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){


    super.setEntityManagerFactory (EntityManagerFactory);
}



public abstract class JpaDAO<K, E> extends JpaDaoSupport {
protected Class<E> entityClass;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public JpaDAO() {
    ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass()
            .getGenericSuperclass();
    this.entityClass = (Class<E>) genericSuperclass
            .getActualTypeArguments()[1];
}

public void persist(E entity)  {
    getJpaTemplate().persist(entity);
}
```

service:

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("springGwtServices/customerService")
public interface CustomerService extends RemoteService
```

serviceImpl:

```
@Service("customerService")


public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

@Autowired
private CustomerDAO CustomerDAO;

@PostConstruct
public void init() throws Exception {
}

@PreDestroy
public void destroy() {
}
```

error log:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerDAO': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named amine
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:341)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1055)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:272)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:196)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:543)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:468)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:672)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1093)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named amine
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1403)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.findEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:99)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findNamedEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:510)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:492)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:642)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:633)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:147)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotation
```

Comment: duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158159/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named

Comment: Not the same,the persistence.xml contains the provider

Comment: do you have the hibernate-entitymanager.jar inside your libs ?

Comment: Thank you a lot,my error log  changes..it should be under my classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your persistence.xml file is not placed correctly, theerfore cannot be found on the classpath.

It should be placed inside META-INF folder.

Comment: Thank you,but the persistence.xml is placed under META-INF folder.

Comment: Is this a WAR ? If so, you must create a a src/META-INF folder, instead of placing it on Webapp/META-INF

Comment: No Not under the war,but under src/META-INF