# no Persistence provider for EntityManager named ***

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, mamp

I know this has been asked a lot on SO, but they don't offer solutions to my problem:

I'm using a project with JPA, cloned from someone else with the exact same settings (same OS, same IDE, same database name, also in MAMP)

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named persistentie
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at DatabaseTest.main(DatabaseTest.java:29)
```

My persistence.xml (both in folder /META-INF/ and /WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/, as suggested on multiple other questions on SO):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="persistentie" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>Domein.Student</class>
    <class>Domein.Onderzoeksdomein</class>
    <class>Domein.Promotor</class>
    <class>Domein.Gebruiker</class>
    <class>Domein.Campus</class>
    <class>Domein.Presentatie</class>
    <class>Domein.Dag</class>
    <class>Domein.Lokaal</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Project2-DB?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This line is where it gets the Exception:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistentie");
```

There's no code before this, it's the first line of the main.

I'm using MAMP, NetBeans 7.4 with `Persistence (JPA 2.1)` and OS X.

I'm completely lost here... As I didn't change anything from my friend's code, this should work right?

Also I checked out the source of javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(String name) and I found that resolver.getPersistenceProviders() returns an empty List. I don't have the experience in JPA to know what this means though.

Comment: do you have all needed jars for it? It seems there is no EM in your classpath;

Comment: Could you add this as an answer? This works. Maybe give a bit more info for future visitors?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No Persistence provider for EntityManager named](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158159/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't `EM` jar in your classpath. Simply add this :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

For EclipseLink add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```