# Maven/Eclipse: Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I know there are other questions on SO about this issue, but none of the solutions have worked for me. I'm using maven to build a java project in eclipse, and I have my persistence.xml file in the src/main/resource/META_INF folder. But when I try to mvn install, I always get this error:

```
No Persistence provider for EntityManager named plasma.persistence
```

Looking through the console output it appears to be caused by this:

```
[org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser] - HHH000318: Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath
```

Here is my persistence.xml file:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="plasma.persistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432:xxxxx"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="xxxxx"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="xxxxx"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="5"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="5"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I have tried right clicking on the project and adding the META_INF folder to the build path, and it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The proper home for the persistence file should be src/main/resources/META-INF. In the question, you mention src/main/resource/META_INF. Note, there should be an 's' in resources and a dash (-) in META-INF, not an underscore. Are those just typos in the question? If not, fix the path and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

I put a exclude and the maven stopped to put the persistence.xml. I had to use brutal force to fix:

```
    <resources>
        <!-- After this maven stopped to put parsistence.xml-->
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/CATALINA_HOME/conf</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>log4j.properties</exclude>
                <exclude>jpa_stocks.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <!-- Brutal force to fix -->
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/META-INF</directory>
            <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>persistence.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Comment: Note that it's not the excludes, it's the fact that the `<resource>` was defined at all. As soon as any resource elements are added, it's up to the developer to define everything needed explicitly. The Maven defaults are no longer used. This is why the second `<resource>` was required in the above example.