# how to load JPA jar with persistence.xml from outside of war file in jboss

Tags: java, jpa, jboss, persistence.xml

I have JPA jar with persistence.xml and want to deploy in Jboss7.

Problem is that, i can't put inside WAR file(i know we can load from war file).

I have created module in jboss and placed jar file with including persistence.xml file inside META-INF\ of the jar 
with ref: 
http://javahowto.blogspot.sg/2007/06/where-to-put-persistencexml-in-web-app.html
[Maven/Eclipse: Could not find any META-INF/persistence.xml file in the classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835472/maven-eclipse-could-not-find-any-meta-inf-persistence-xml-file-in-the-classpath)

After that jar file loaded, but persistence.xml not loaded.

Is it possible to load persistence.xml from jar file ?

if possible, can someone please let me know, where to place inside jar

Thanks

Comment: if you use Spring, check `persistenceXmlLocation` property

Comment: i am not using spring

Comment: Do you use a jboss-deployment-structure.xml? How does it look like? Did you export META-INF?

Answer (score 0):

If it is just about the persistence.xml, you could use a deployment-overlay. See e.g. https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Deployment+Overlays