# my JPA Provider does not detected

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have seen many Question and Answer that is related my question but none of them solved my problem.

I have written a simple JPA  example for myself but I got this error

```
  SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
  SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
  SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
  Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named k
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:69)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
at Runner.main(Runner.java:13)
```

this is my persistence file in META-INF/persistence.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         version="1.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="k" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>FirstEntity</class>

    <properties>

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="myjava123"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

this is my entity class:

```
@Entity(name = "first")
public class FirstEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
int id;
@Column

String name;

@OneToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name = "Id")
SecondEntity secondEntity;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}



}
```

and at last my runner:

```
public class Runner {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    FirstEntity firstEntity = new FirstEntity();
    SecondEntity secondEntity = new SecondEntity();

    EntityManager entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("k").createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    firstEntity.setName("ali");

    entityManager.close();




}

}
```

What is the problem??

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158159/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named

Comment: i have checked it but I observe all

Answer (score 2):

It seems like "hibernate-entitymanager.jar" not in your classpath.
Just put it in your /lib folder or update dependencies.

Comment: i add it but no difference

Comment: @Stefan post you a great link with dissusion on this problem. Check it for solution. But most common reason is libraries.