# hibernate.cfg.xml file not able to find out mapped class and throwing - Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity:

Tags: java, hibernate

I tried to see all the questions on this topic but none of them helped me, I have tried all possible way to resolve the issue, but not able to.I want to understand where I have done mistake in my code.

My project structure is

```
 hibernateOnline
       |---------src/main/java
                       |------------com.hibernateOnline.data
                                               |---------HibernateUtil.java
                       |------------com.hibernateOnline.data.entities
                                               |------------------User.java
       |---------src/main/resources
                       |------------hibernate.cfg.xml
```

Below is my User class where I have used all the JPA annotation not specific to hibernate

```
package com.hibernateOnline.data.entities;

@Entity

@Table(name = "finances_user")

public class User   

{

   @Id

   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)

   @Column(name="USER_ID")

   private Long userId;

   @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
   private String firstName;

   @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
   private String lastName;

   @Column(name="BIRTH_DATE")
   private Date birthDate;

   @Column(name="EMAIL_ADDRESS")
   private String emailAddress;

   @Column(name="LAST_UPDATED_DATE")
   private Date lastUpdatedDate;

   @Column(name="LAST_UPDATED_BY")
   private String lastUpdatedBy;

   @Column(name="CREATED_DATE")
   private Date createdDate;

   @Column(name="CREATED_BY")
   private String createdBy;

   public Long getUserId() {
       return userId;
   }

   public void setUserId(Long userId) {
       this.userId = userId;
   }

   public String getFirstName() {
       return firstName;
   }

   public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
       this.firstName = firstName;
   }

   public String getLastName() {
       return lastName;
   }

   public void setLastName(String lastName) {
       this.lastName = lastName;
   }

   public Date getBirthDate() {
       return birthDate;
   }

   public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
      this.birthDate = birthDate;
   }

   public String getEmailAddress() {
       return emailAddress;
   }

   public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdatedDate() {
        return lastUpdatedDate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedDate(Date lastUpdatedDate) {
        this.lastUpdatedDate = lastUpdatedDate;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public String getLastUpdatedBy() {
        return lastUpdatedBy;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedBy(String lastUpdatedBy) {
        this.lastUpdatedBy = lastUpdatedBy;
    }
}
```

Next is the HibernateUtils class where I am creating the sessionFactory

```
package com.hibernateOnline.data;

public class HibernateUtil 
{
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            return configuration
                   .buildSessionFactory(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                            .build());
            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              throw new RuntimeException(
                "There was an error building the factory");
            }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Now the configuration file "hibernate.cfg.xml" which I am using for configuration of MySQL database and to mapped the User class

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">****</property>
        <property name="connection.password">*****</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>


        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping class="com.hibernateOnline.data.entities.User"/>

  </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

After done with all those things when I am trying to run the program it showing below error it is not able to find out the User class

```
DEBUG - begin
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.hibernateOnline.data.entities.User
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:776)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1451)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:678)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:670)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:665)
    at com.hibernateOnline.data.Application.main(Application.java:25)
```

Can anyone please help me out to solve this problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the hbm.xml to cfg.xml

Comment: thanks Pritam for reply, I have added    <mapping resource="User.hbm.xml"/> to my cfg.xml file but still not working...please help me to resolve the issue...

Answer (score 0):

you need change org.hibernate to javax.persistence in annotation Entity

Answer (score 0):

**JPA annotations and Hibernate config files don't work together.** An entity defined by annotating a class with JPA annotation @Entity will not be visible to hibernate configuration file as an entity. Hence, it is not able to find it and gives and error.

**You need to choose one between JPA OR Hibernate.** Then -

1. If you choose to use JPA then you need to make a persistence.xml file. Look at the link - https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-tutorial-jpa.html for all the settings. In JPA settings you will need to provide ORM adapter/provider for which you can use Hibernate provider. But remember that all your annotations/settings/configurations will need to be as per JPA standards.
2. Else, if you want to use Hibernate then similarly do annotations/settings/configurations as per Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by @Dhruv rai Puri.

**JPA annotations and Hibernate config files don't work together.**. To get a solution to this question, you may visit [No Persistence provider for EntityManager named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158159/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named/40994767#40994767). Complete solution to this question is provided using **Hibernate 5.2.5 Final**.