# Getting an HTTP Status 500 - org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Specified cfg.xml file does not exist

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, tomcat, hibernate.cfg.xml

I am working on a project using Java, Spring MVC, and Hibernate (my IDE is IntelliJ). When I try to access the URL (that makes a simple call to my Oracle database via Hibernate) on my localhost after deploying to Tomcat, I receive the following error:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Specified
>   cfg.xml file
>   [C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\bin\src\main\resources\hibernate.cfg.xml]
>   does not exist

**My question:** why is my program looking in my apache-tomcat folder? I never specified anything in my code to look in that folder, and all of my tests pass when it comes to using Hibernate.

**Approaches taken so far to resolve the problem:**

1. Tried rebuilding my WAR file from scratch
2. Doing a maven clean, compile, install then redeploying to Tomcat
3. [org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [/HibernateTest/src/hibernate.cfg.xml]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35725306/org-hibernate-internal-util-config-configurationexception-could-not-locate-cfg)
4. http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-load-hibernate-cfg-xml-from-different-directory/
5. [Location of hibernate.cfg.xml in project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736594/location-of-hibernate-cfg-xml-in-project)

None of the approaches listed above worked out for me. I have provided my code below along with my file structure to help:

---

My SessionFactory method:

```
private static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    String hibernatePropsFilePath = "src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml";
    File hibernatePropsFile = new File(hibernatePropsFilePath);

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure(hibernatePropsFile);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Request.class);

    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());

    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    return sessionFactory;
}
```

---

Application.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ourApp")
public class Application {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getRequestResponse", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String returnRequestResponse() {
        RequestService requestService = new RequestService();
        Request request = requestService.findById(1);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(request);
    }
}
```

---

File structure:

[image]

---

#### Update

This works if I place my Hibernate configuration file in my Tomcat folder.

My tests do fail now as I tried to implement shankarsh15's solution in my SessionFactory method. Here is my setUp function before my tests run:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(MyService.class)
            .addAnnotatedClass(MyModel.class);
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//servername.mycompany.com:12345/abcdefg");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "username");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "password");

    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
}
```

Updated hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@//servername.mycompany.com:12345/abcdefg</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.username">username</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="com.mycompany.project.modelName.model.MyModelClass"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should not have been manually checking for a hibernate configuration file. Instead, my `getSessionFactory()` method should have looked like the following:

```
private static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(MyClassNameHere.class);
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly specifying hibernate.cfg.xml file, Please rewrite your code as follows:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
ServiceRegistryBuilder registry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder();
registry.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = registry.buildServiceRegistry();
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

Just make sure that **hibernate.cfg.xml** is at the root of the **classpath** which in your case is true, since it is under **src/main/resources**.

Comment: ServiceRegistryBuilder is deprecated. I am currently using Hibernate 5.1.0. Any alternatives to this?

Comment: Please try :  Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        ServiceRegistry sr = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

        SessionFactory sf = configuration.buildSessionFactory(sr);

Comment: Thanks, but now when I receive a "org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister:" I suspect that it is my setUp() within the JUnit test suite. I posted the code and updated configuration file above.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried specifying full path for your config file? or try without specifying src for eg. main/resources/.... and why it is searching in your tomcat folder instead of searching in your source code?

Comment: Yes I did it still doesn't work. My question is the same as the one you're asking; why is it searching in my Tomcat folder instead of searching in my source code? :)