# Hibernate connect with hibernate.cfg.xml file error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I can’t connect my config file, it gives an error, I tried these methods [org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [/HibernateTest/src/hibernate.cfg.xml]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35725306/org-hibernate-internal-util-config-configurationexception-could-not-locate-cfg)
but they don’t work
This is my code

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
            .configure("./hibernate.cfg.xml")
            .addAnnotatedClass(Employee.class)
            .buildSessionFactory();

    try {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Employee employee = new Employee("Marsel", "Charginov", "IT", 500);
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(employee);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }finally {
        sessionFactory.close();
    }
```

This is my error

```
февр. 21, 2022 11:07:56 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.3.Final
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could         
not locate cfg.xml resource [./hibernate.cfg.xml]
```

This is my file structure

- src

  - main

    - java

      - hibernate

        - Main.java

          - entity

            - Employee.java
  - resources

    - hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: Looks like you put your config file into the directory `src/resources` whereas it should be `src/main/resources`.

Comment: it still not working

Comment: Try `hibernate.cfg.xml` instead of `./hibernate.cfg.xml`

Comment: it still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate xml file should be inside src . Looks like it is inside main package

If it is EE, always put it into WEB-INF/classes directory (compiled files are stored there).