# Error message: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I encounter a problem to run my java program with JPA annotation. it looks I did not set environment correctly. Here is my error message:

[image]

here is my project structure:

[image]

Here is my persistence.xml

```
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="IFP" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <class>gov.faa.infra.ifp.ifp_hibernate_test.ProcSegment</class>


        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, htm" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion" value="true" />

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@jamcdfdndb500.amc.faa.gov:1521:dnavln"/>
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@jamcdfdndb500.amc.faa.gov:1521:dnavln" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="xxxxxx"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxxxxx"/>

            <property name="javax.persistence.query.timeout" value="1000000"/>
        </properties>
</persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Here is my code to create entity manager:

```
    package gov.faa.infra.ifp.ifp_hibernate_test;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class AccessHibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("IFP");
        EntityManager entityManager= entityManagerfactory.createEntityManager();

        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

        ProcId procId=new ProcId(6688L, 1, "C", new Integer(0));

        ProcSegment procSegment=entityManager.find(ProcSegment.class, procId);

        System.out.println(procSegment.toString());

        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

    }

}
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>gov.faa.infra.ifp</groupId>
  <artifactId>ifp-hibernate-test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>ifp-hibernate-test</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <hibernate.core.version>3.6.10.Final</hibernate.core.version>
    <junit.version>4.6</junit.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>siap</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>build.txt</include>
                    <include>log4j.properties</include>
                    <include>siap.properties</include>
                    <include>correlation.properties</include>
                    <include>META-INF/persistence.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <extdirs>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib</extdirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalClasspathElements>
                        <additionalClasspathElement>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/restlet-2.0m3.jar</additionalClasspathElement>                       
                    </additionalClasspathElements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I tried to set up environment as past posts suggested, but it did not work, I am using Eclipse. One thing I am confused is about setting up class path in the suggestion. Can anyone give me a hint? I would appreciate it.

Sam

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No Persistence provider for EntityManager named](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158159/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified a provider

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

But you don't have a jar with `HibernatePersistence` class in the class path. This class resides in the [`hibernate-entitymanager`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager) jar of a corresponding version.

You just need to add `hibernate-entitymanager` to your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.core.version}</version>
</dependency>
```