# No Persistence provider for EntityManager named miageTP13

Tags: jpa, persistence-provider

I have a problem with my data persistance. I do not see where is the problem. Can you help me ?

The error in Tomcat:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named miageTP13
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:89)
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:60)
    dao.impl.TeamDAOImpl.getEntityManager(TeamDAOImpl.java:20)
    dao.impl.TeamDAOImpl.insert(TeamDAOImpl.java:36)
    controller.TeamController.createTeam(TeamController.java:119)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: You seem to not be running the code you think you're running. Clean/rebuild/redeploy/restart and update the question accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No Persistence provider for EntityManager named](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158159/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named)

Comment: I have add <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider> but i halways the same problem