# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence-provider

I am trying to connect database using Hibernate on Intellij Idea.

Bean file is auto-generated based on Hibernate entity class.

```
public class SirketEntityManagedBean {

    private EntityManagerFactory myEntityManagerFactory;

    public SirketEntityManagedBean() {
        myEntityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    }

    // ...
}
```

When I run it, below exception is thrown:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named hibernate.cfg.xml
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:69)
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
>   beans.SirketEntityManagedBean.<init>(SirketEntityManagedBean.java:40)
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
>     com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:186)
>     com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:100)
>     com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
>     com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
>     com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
>     com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
>     com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>     com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>     org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:71)
>     org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:161)
>     org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
>     com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
>     javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
>     org.primefaces.component.panelmenu.PanelMenu.getModel(PanelMenu.java:84)
>     org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(BaseMenuRenderer.java:108)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903)
>     javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
>     org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:84)
>     org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:71)
>     org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:49)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
>     com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:451)
>     com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
>     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
>     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
>     javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Here is persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>hib.OrtamEntity</class>
        <class>hib.SorumluEntity</class>
        <class>hib.SirketEntity</class>
        <class>hib.VpnkullaniciEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//XXX.X.XX.XX:1521/PROD"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="XXTEST"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="XXTEST"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And this is project directory:

[image: maven_dir]

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: If the init is not called, how is it PrimeFaces related then? Any errors in the logging? What if you run the app in 'development mode' where do you fine that it is a bean? faces-config.xml? Please create an [mcve]

Comment: So what part of that stacktrace is not clear? Your title is wrong, your tagging was wrong (but 'wrongly corrected')

Comment: Do you have persistence.xml? I strongly feel that your persistent unit name is not "hibernate.cfg.xml". Your configuration is incorrect. Please post the persistence.xml here, if you have one. Make sure the persistence.xml is your classpath too. You can refer to this question to get more idea - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158159/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named

Comment: I have edited question @Manish

Comment: @Erdinc - I posted an answer to this question. You need to change to createEntityManagerFactory("NewPersistenceUnit")

Comment: @Manish did not work. Same error.

Comment: @Erdinç - Make sure the persistence.xml is in the classpath.

Comment: @Erdinç - Can you please check if the persistence.xml is in this directory /WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/

Comment: @Manish This time i get  >javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: @Manish I think it is related with hibernate-annotations jar. I have manually added jar but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: @Erdinç You seem to be right about hibernate-annotations jar. But this issue is not relevant to the question which you posted. You might want to post another question for this issue. Please upvote the answer if it solved your original issue.

Comment: You clearly do NOT need some hibernate.cfg.xml file when using JPA (and persistence.xml)

Answer (score 3):

The `createEntityManagerFactory` method takes in the name of a `persistence-unit`. Some `Hibernate` config file (*hibernate.cfg.xml*) is not the name of a `persistence-unit`. A `persistence-unit` is specified in file *persistence.xml*. This would be adequately described in any JPA documentation, which you evidently haven't read

Answer (score 1):

The `createEntityManagerFactory` method takes in the `persistent unit` as argument. The persistent unit is described in a file named `persistence.xml` and this *file should be in the classpath of your project*.

For example if your persistent unit name is "exampledb", then the method call would be -

> EntityManagerFactory exDb =
>   Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("exampledb");

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158159/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named) question too see an example of persistence.xml

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of the bean definitions. Did you define bean definitions on xml config file? If you did, check the class names on the config file. If you didn't, add `@ManagedBean(name = "sirketEntity")` on the top of you class definition.

Like this:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "sirketEntity")
public class SirketEntityManagedBean {
```