# No Persistence provider found

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, ejb-3.0

I am getting the following error when I am using Jboss 4.2.3 GA and configured my ms-sql.ds file. I created an Entity Bean EJB3 and I am trying to access that Entity bean from EJB 2.1 Session Bean. First of all, I wanted to check if it is possible. Because when I use `EntityManager` or `EntityManagerFactory`,
my `EntityManager` is comming as null. Also instead if I use `EntityManagerFactory`, it gives
an error saying:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for
>   EntityManager named EjbComponentPU

Below is my class

```
public class TestBean implements SessionBean {

//pass persistence unit to entityManager.
@PersistenceContext(unitName="EjbComponentPU")
 private EntityManager entitymanager;
```

My Project folder structure is:

`src` - has the all the packages.
Inside that I have `META-INF` folder which has the `persistence.xml` file

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you show the contents of your persistence.xml?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158159/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named

Comment: Hi, this is my persistence.xml file.

Comment: Hi , also wanted to confirm one more thing. My session beans are in EJB 2.1, and Entity Beans are in EJB3.0. Is that an issue when i am trying to access the EntityManager from EJB 2.1 Session beans?

Answer (score 0):

this is my persistence.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="EjbComponentPU" transaction-type="JTA">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>java:/testDS</jta-data-source>
       <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
   </persistence-unit>
```

Comment: This seems to be really short. Where are the dialect, db driver, security properties are set?

Comment: Hi,I figured out the solution in my case, in case it may help someone. I had to put the persistence.xml file under Resources/META-INF directory and that worked as ant file put all resources in the classpath.

Comment: Hi mikereem,db properties are set in ms-ds.xml file