# no persistence provider for entitymanager error JPA/hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I want to add database and persist data using JPA/hibernate. I've persistence.xml in right place but I'm getting "no persistence provider for entitymanager" error. Database is in mysql. Any suggestion is much appreciated. Here is my code:

**Folder structure:**

[image]

**servlet:**

```
@WebServlet("/Reservations")
public class Reservations extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            if( request != null) {

                Enumeration<String> names = request.getParameterNames();
                while(names.hasMoreElements()) {
                    String name = names.nextElement();
                    System.out.println(name + " : " + request.getParameter(name));
                }

                String pickUpDate = request.getParameter("pickUpDate");
                Integer totalPass = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("totalPass"));                

                ReservationEntity reservation = new ReservationEntity(pickUpDate, totalPass);
                ReservationSevice reservationSevice = new ReservationSevice();
                reservationSevice.createReservation(reservation);
            }else{
                System.out.println("#############Request is null#########");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception occured");
        }
    }
}
```

**Entity class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "reservations_db")
public class ReservationEntity {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id; 
    @Column(name = "pickUpDate")
    private String pickUpDate;

    @Column(name = "totalPass")
    private Integer totalPass;

    public ReservationEntity() 
    {       
    }

    public ReservationEntity(String pickUpDate, Integer totalPass) 
    {
        this.setPickUpDate(pickUpDate);
        this.setTotalPass(totalPass);

    }

    public int getId() {
    return id;
}

 public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
    public String getPickUpDate() {
        return pickUpDate;
    }
    public void setPickUpDate(String pickUpDate) {
        this.pickUpDate = pickUpDate;
    }

    public Integer getTotalPass() {
        return totalPass;
    }
    public void setTotalPass(Integer totalPass) {
        this.totalPass = totalPass;
    }
}
```

**Service class for JPA persistence:**

```
public class ReservationSevice 
{
    static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ReservationsPU");
    private static EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(); 

    public void createReservation (ReservationEntity reservation)
    {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(reservation);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

**persistence.xml:**

```
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="ReservationsPU">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password" />
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**error:**

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named ReservationsPU
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at com.welcomelimo.service.ReservationSevice.<init>(ReservationSevice.java:11)
    at com.welcomelimo.controller.Reservations.doPost(Reservations.java:56)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2508)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2497)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception occured
```

**Update**

I'm adding the lib folder in order to show the jar files I've added for the project, since I'm not using maven.

[image]

**Update 2**

I ended up using maven and it's working now. For pom.xml, see below @Surace's answer.

Comment: Btw your entity should have an id.

Comment: @ MouseEvent , I've an id. I updated the question

Comment: @Scary Wombat, according to JPA doc, I need to add just persistence.xml where I configure persistence unit. I didn;t see anything about web.xml. Are you saying I've to add configuration in web.xml as well?

Comment: @JoeZ I am not sure myself, hence the comment

Comment: As per you updated question, what is the **build error** in eclipse

Comment: @scary-wombat, the same build error

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158159/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named

Comment: Are you sure `persistence.xml` is really in the final WAR?  I believe putting it in `src/META-INF/persistence.xml` may not be a proper place to get it properly included

Comment: @AdrianShum, JPA doc says, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbrj/index.html . So, src as root is an option. But, how can I check the final war file in eclipse? I gave my project folder structure in eclipse in the question. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot see any place in the JPA spec saying you can put the things under `src/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your persistence.xml to

```
<persistence version="2.1"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="ReservationsPU">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Add following dependencies in your pom.xml if you are using Maven

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.37</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: I wanna use JPA 2.1 version, that's why I used this provider. But I tried your one as well, same error. For some reason, it's not getting persistence.xml configuration. I followed all the steps according to Jpa doc.

Comment: You should also add dependencies in your pom.xml.

Comment: May be I have missed but I cannot see OP mentioning that he is using Maven.  I believe it is better to mention `hibernate-entitymanager.jar` should be in classpath, and use pom.xml as example if he is using Maven

Comment: Actually I believe quite possibly that OP is NOT using Maven, based on the directory structure he showed

Comment: Yes @AdrianShum  you are right he is not using Maven. Joez have you tried above answer? Do you have jar in your library folder?

Comment: @Surace, I tried your answer by changing the provider name and putting hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto value as "create", but no luck. Same error.

Comment: @Surace, I'm adding the library folder in the question as an update.

Comment: It works in my machine . But i test it in Maven project.

Comment: @Surace, can you put the pom.xml file? I would like to use maven. Thanks.

Comment: Please update your question and tell you are using maven otherwise others will confuse .

Answer (score 0):

I think the matter is with eclipse. Eclipse may only allow running JPA if it is explicitly set as a JPA project.

You can convert your project into a JPA project, by opening the context menu in the explorer.