# Unable to locate persistence unit in web application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Stack Trace :

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Sample
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at cm.cvs.service.UserInfoService.<init>(UserInfoService.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 24 more
```

Jar used :

[image]

Placed persistence.xml under META-INF folder.
[image]

Persistence.xml

[image]

In persistence.xml, i have already given provider property.

Comment: WTF is that "provider" ? You are supposed to specify the IMPLEMENTATION class of a JPA Provider there, not the interface. So define your implementation being used DataNucleus? EclipseLink? Hibernate? OpenJPA ? and look in their docs for the provider name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No Persistence provider for EntityManager named](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158159/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named)

Comment: @ChristianW it is not a duplicate. from the answer of "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named", i have already used that answer to resolve it. but still it was not working.

Comment: So in your current persistence.xml you have <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> as implementation instead of javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider ?

Comment: Now the issue got resolved and i have no provider tag is used in my persistence.xml

Answer (score 0):

When doing JPA under web application project, place persistance.xml in "src/META-INF" path and remove the below line from persistence.xml

```
<provider>javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

Note: META-INF folder was newly created under src folder.

Got reference from this [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html) to resolve the error.

First tried to create simple java jpa application to check whether i am getting the same here also.

But it worked fine. when i replaced the java application persistence.xml with my web application persistence.xml, that time it throwed same error.

after comparing both persistence.xml, i removed the line "javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider" from the web application's persistence.xml and kept under src/META-INF then it worked fine.

Comment: which completely ignores the root cause ... putting the CORRECT value for "provider" for your chosen JPA provider. You can only not put the "provider" element when you only have 1 provider in your CLASSPATH. As soon as you have multiple present then this "solution" fails