# Using REST via GlassFish server- How do I allow updates on a list using HTML input and return a JSON object?

Tags: java, json, rest, glassfish, objectdb

I am using GlassFish 4.1, using REST services within my web.xml (using JAX-RS,) and running queries on my temporary ObjectDB database. I need the input to by checked and return a JSON object with my desired information.

I have tested the entire program off of the server, and it works perfectly. However, while I am hosting it on the local port 8080 and I enter a valid search entry, when it attempts to add to the list, I get an error:

```
Warning: StandardWrapperValve[DataSearch2]: Servlet.service() for servlet DataSearch2 threw exception
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named $objectdb/db/customerDetails.odb
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
```

If I run the HTML and submit a search that will return 0 results I DO get a blank JSON file back!

But if I run a valid search that would return actual information, I get the "no persistence" error.

This is happening when I have the driver update its own list. I AM sure that I have the correct .jar in the web.inf folder.

Any idea why this would be happening?

I did find a resource outlining a similar problem in *[No Persistence provider for EntityManager named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158159/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named)*, but since it is not the same framework, the answers don't really help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that objectdb-jee.jar is missing.

Comment: I definitely have the objectdb-jee.jar in both my resource library and my web-inf library...

Comment: Still, somehow, JPA cannot find the ObjectDB jar file. You may start with an ObjectDB web tutorial (http://www.objectdb.com/tutorial). Assuming it would work - change the project step by step to your application.

Comment: so youre 100% sure it is the jar file not being recognized? I'll definitely look into it.

Comment: OK this WAS the problem! Thank you very much. What had happened was, i added both the objectDB.jar AND the ObjectDb-jee.jar and it appears it was trying to reference the objectDb.jar instead of the objectDB-jee.jar. Once i removed the ObjectDb.jar it worked!