# Gradle project JUnit - No persistence provider

Tags: java, jpa, build.gradle, junit4

In my Java gradle project I use the JPA (with persistence.xml) to access a database and I want to run JUnit4 tests.

My build.gradle file contains these lines:

```
    ...
    providedCompile group: 'org.eclipse.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence', version: '2.1.0'
    testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-all', version: '1.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    sourceSets{    
        main{
            java{
                srcDir 'src/java'
                srcDir 'test/java'
            }
        }
        test {
            java {
              srcDir 'unitTests/src'
            }
        } 
    }
    ...
```

the persistence.xml file is located under src/conf

The (Web-)application runs fine -> persistence provider & persistence.xml is found.

However when running JUnit tests an exception is thrown when the database is accessed:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for
>   EntityManager named xyz at
>   javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)

I tried several things like adding

```
 testCompile group: 'org.eclipse.persistence', name: 'eclipselink', version: '2.5.2'
 testCompile group: 'org.eclipse.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence', version: '2.1.0'
 testCompile group: 'org.eclipse.persistence', name: 'org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql', version: '2.5.2'
```

to build.gradle

or copying persistence.xml to the unitTests directory

but I always receive the exception above :-(

Any more suggestions what might go wrong and what might help are appreciated!

Comment: This is a dup of many many posts on here. You get that message IF EITHER the JPA provider selected is not in the CLASSPATH, OR the `persistence.xml` is not found under META-INF from the root of the CLASSPATH. Only you can check which one of those you have got wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No Persistence provider for EntityManager named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158159/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named)

Comment: paste your `persistence.xml` here. If you copy the file to the correct directory during testing then the missing tag there is the only option.

Comment: I am pretty sure that my persistence.xml is correct since the application itself runs fine!
The JUnit tests start as well which means that the hamcrest and junit jar files are found.

Comment: So the junit and hamcrest are in the correct classpath for the tests. But why not the JPA provider?
I assume that there is something wrong with the build.gradle part for tests or the persistence.xml is in the wrong dir or I have to tell the test task where to find the persistence.xml