# JPA error when deploying to a tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, jpa, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

I have a javaEE application (webapp) on netbeans (running on glassfish server).
I use the JPA ORM.
I imported all the right jar on MAVEN.
When I want to deploy the WAR file of this webapp on a distant server (running on tomcat)  JPA  makes it crash...

I have an error 500 on the server:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for
>   EntityManager named
>   com.mycompany_EmployeesManagementApplication2_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU
>     javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
>     javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
>     models.DataTransaction.(DataTransaction.java:31)
>     controllers.SingleController.doGet(SingleController.java:37)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Here is my pom.xml:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>EmployeesManagementApplication2</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>EmployeesManagementApplication2</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and here is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="com.mycompany_EmployeesManagementApplication2_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:app/awsrds</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My persistence file is correctly located in ressources/META-INF

Thank you very much

Comment: What is very strange is that everything work smoothly on my machine under netbeans / glassfish but the war file on the distant server  doesn't work ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No Persistence provider for EntityManager named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158159/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that Tomcat is not a full Java EE server, it is only a servlet container and does not provide JPA, which Glassfish does. If you wish to use JPA with Tomcat then you need to include it in your WAR as a library.

If you are using pure JPA and not any Eclipselink features then you could use TomEE which includes Apache OpenJPA as an alternative JPA provider. Alternatively you could remain using GlassFish or Payara which include Eclipselink and do not need you to include it.

Comment: Ok seems right. Is it easy to setup payara in my project or will it means to change all my code ?

Comment: @JohnDoe Payara is a fork of Glassfish, and can be set up in the same way.