# No Persistence provider for EntityManager named xxxx

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, java-11, persistence.xml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0JWU.png)currently Hibernate. I create simply project. I did everything as is in course but i get "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named xxxx". I dont know what is wrong. I find many solutions but none work with me.

```
package pl.javastart.dao;

import pl.javastart.model.Book;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
public class BookDaoImpl implements BookDao {

    private EntityManagerFactory emFactory;
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public BookDaoImpl() {
        emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPersistenceUnit");
        entityManager = emFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void save(Book book) {
        EntityTransaction tx = entityManager.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        entityManager.persist(book);
        tx.commit();
    }

    public Book get(Long id) {
        Book book = entityManager.find(Book.class, id);
        return book;
    }

    public void cleanUp() {
        entityManager.close();
        emFactory.close();
    }
}
```

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="myPersistenceUnit"
                      transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
                      value="drop-and-create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>JPAbezSpringa</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpabezbezsprinsaa</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>10</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named myPersistenceUnit
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at pl.javastart.dao.BookDaoImpl.(BookDaoImpl.java:16)
    at pl.javastart.main.Main.main(Main.java:10)

Comment: Try adding the `<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>` inside `<persistence-unit>` tag.

Comment: the same exception, maybe path persistence file is incorrect. I added photo with my structure project. I have persistance file to resources -> META-INF->persistence.xml

Comment: I using java 11

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1285436/9593249

define the persistence provider name:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

if you are using Hibernate 4 or for Hibernate 5

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

after 
`<persistence-unit name="myPersistenceUnit">`

Comment: the same exception, maybe path persistence file is incorrect. I added photo with my structure project. I have persistance file to resources -> META-INF->persistence.xml