# JavaEE Hibernate + Glassfish server : No Persistence provider for EntityManager

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I've been on this problem for more than a week...

I'm pretty new to the world of JaveEE, Hibernate, Glassfish, etc.

I'm using JavaEE/Glassfish and Hibernate to create a little project for school.

1) We're supposed to get a list of flights from a local database using Hibernate.
2) We're supposed to get the result through a GET request using a REST-api

My "routing" class :

```java
package routes;

import DAO.DAOUtilisateurs;
import DAO.DaoVolsManager;
import controllers.VolsBD;
import models.Vol;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Path("/vols")
public class Vols {

    DaoVolsManager manager = new DaoVolsManager();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Vol> getVol() {

        return manager.getAllVols();
    }
}
```

Which refers to my flights entity manager class `DAOVolsManager` :

```java
package DAO;

import com.sun.istack.NotNull;
import models.Vol;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class DaoVolsManager {

    // Create an EntityManagerFactory when you start the application.
    private static final EntityManagerFactory ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("VolDB");

    /**
     * Renvoie tous les vols de la base
     * @return Liste de vols
     */
    public List<Vol> getAllVols() {
        List<Vol> vols = new ArrayList<>();

        EntityManager manager = ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY.createEntityManager();

        try {
            vols = manager.createQuery("FROM Vol", Vol.class).getResultList();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            manager.close();
        }
        return vols;
    }
}
```

Hibernate `persistence.xml` file :

```xml
<persistence version="2.0"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="VolDB" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <!-- Persistence provider -->
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <!-- Entity classes -->
        <class>models.Vol</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vols" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="**myusername**" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="**mypassword**" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Here come's the problem** : when I'm getting the data in a `Main` class ...

```java
import models.Vol;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    // Create an EntityManagerFactory when you start the application.
    private static final EntityManagerFactory ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("VolDB");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Print all the Students
        List<Vol> vols = readAll();
        if (vols != null) {
            for (Vol v : vols) {
                System.out.println(v.getNumVol());
            }
        }

        // NEVER FORGET TO CLOSE THE ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY
        ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY.close();
    }

    /**
     * Read all the Students.
     *
     * @return a List of Vols
     */
    public static List readAll() {

        List vols = null;

        // Create an EntityManager
        EntityManager manager = ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction transaction = null;

        try {
            // Get a transaction
            transaction = manager.getTransaction();
            // Begin the transaction
            transaction.begin();

            // Get a List of Students
            vols = manager.createQuery("SELECT v FROM Vol v",
                    Vol.class).getResultList();

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // If there are any exceptions, roll back the changes
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            // Print the Exception
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Close the EntityManager
            manager.close();
        }
        return vols;
    }
}
```

... everything works fine and data is showing in local console but once I try to get the data by launching my Glassfish server and typing the **good** url in the browser I'm getting an `Error 500: Internal Server Error` saying `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named VolDB`

I tried to move my `persistence.xml` in different locations with no success.

Here's my current file tree :
[image: project file tree]

What am I supposed to do to avoid that error and get Hibernate to work with Glassfish ? 
Finally, once I will solve that problem what should I be aware of to make that work on a production server ?

**EDIT** : Added the Hibernate libraries to Glassfish in Intellij `Project Structure > Artifacts` and finally it works !

Comment: I take it you already checked the things listed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58293564/jpa-no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named-name-here and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158159/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named and that you added the Hibernate libraries to Glassfish? BTW which version of Glassfish and Hibernate are you using?

Comment: `and that you added the Hibernate libraries to Glassfish?` actually I didn't knew I had to do that, so I did and finally **it works**. Thanks for your help ! 
By the way I'm using Hibernate 5.4.5 and Glassfish 5

Comment: Glad it worked. There is a "helpful comment" upvote button BTW . ;)