# How to run fix error about persistence.xml

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven, jpa

hi all i got two different error when i run my java apps using hibernate persistence.xml
1. Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named FastMatch
2.Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

for the first error i have add my persistence.xml like this one :
here my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="FastMatch" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
      <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.dxtr.hibernate.newOrderSingleEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
             <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/> 
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://url/tables" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.connection" value="FINEST"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

for the second i have add in my depedency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.48</version>
</dependency>
```

and 
still got error like this one

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named FastMatch
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
        at com.dxtr.Transaction.FastMatchTransaction.FastmatchTransaction.main(FastmatchTransaction.java:12)
```

and here my pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

i have try add javax.persistence.2.2.jar and other solution from other link here but this problem cannot run well

for more information i use mysql5.7 and eclipse for IDE. and for running this code i use aws. i have try all of the code in stackoverflow but still got the problem so how to fix it ?

fuad

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No Persistence provider for EntityManager named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158159/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named)

Comment: i have try using that solution but it is still no working.... so any solution for my problem @GiancarloRomeo?

Comment: for more information i use eclipse neon for build this code